# Error: Unable to access jarfile metabase.jar on Windows 10

Tags: java, sql, metabase

I am trying to run Metabase for SQL queries and data viz. I am getting the following error when I enter: java -jar metabase.jar on the commandline.

`Error: Unable to access jarfile metabase.jar`

I have the most updated version of Java (as the default app for opening JAR files), have enabled "Hidden" windows and have tried jarfix.exe. My OS is Windows 10. I am new to programming.

Answer (score 3):

the command has to be run in the directoryit was installed. so I will assume it is in your downloads directory. cd into that directory the run the command again.

```
cd PATH_TO_DOWNLOADS_DIR/ 
java -jar metabase.jar
```